# Does the server administrator see what sites I visit

Tags: web-browser, webserver

I have seen a lot of answers but here is the peculiarity of mine.

In the office we all have a login to the WiFi,

First with that login, if I use Tor will my visited sites still be logged by the router and traceable back to me (maybe by my login credentials)

Second, if I'm using incognito on any of these other browsers like Chrome, can I be traced (on a Linux Ubuntu OS and a windows OS)

**Note** for both cases I have to login with my WiFi credentials to be able to surf

The WiFi is distributed round the organisation using routers

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102283/can-my-employer-see-that-i-am-using-netflix-on-my-phone-using-their-wifi/102285#102285), or [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72679/differences-between-using-tor-browser-and-vpn/72729#72729)?

Comment: Can they link this back to you? This really depends on a lot of factors. If they're really adamant they'll be able to track down the MAC address of your device, IMEI, and other mobile phone identifiers. This is a lot of work, and in the end still might not link you to the traffic from  [http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102283/can-my-employer-see-that-i-am-using-netflix-on-my-phone-using-their-wifi/102285#102285](this answer) Is it not easier in my case because I have to login first with my credentials?

Comment: You have two questions which are only tangentially related. In that case you should better open two separate questions.

Comment: Sorry about that. Let's focus on the none Tor browsers. My logs can be viewed but Can they link this back to me? I know it's a whole lot of work to do that but don't you think it will be easier in my case because I have to login first with my credentials? I am not a server admin, I'm just a freaky programmer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With TOR, the communication between you and the TOR network is encrypted. Unless the TOR exit node also happens to be on the same network, your administrator will only get encrypted traffic.

[Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en) on web browsers does not affect the network encryption at all. Its effects are localized to your own machine (what site visits are logged in the local history, what form input is saved for auto-complete, what cookie database is used, etc.). An eavesdropping network administrator is not impeded by this.

The actual use-case for incognito mode is when you share the same computer with multiple users and don't want them to know what you did. It's not supposed to protect your anonymity on the network level.

Comment: Let's focus on the none Tor browsers. My logs can be viewed but Can they link this back to me? I know it's a whole lot of work to do that but don't you think it will be easier in my case because I have to login first with my credentials? I am not a server admin, I'm just a freaky programmer!

Comment: @Prodigy What "logs" are you referring to? Those which are created by your browser (or not when in incognito mode) can be viewed when examining your device itself. Regarding "logging into the network": There are many different ways to implement this. Most would allow to link your (non-encrypted) network activity to your user account. Some might allow spoofing, but that depends on implementation details which can not be deduced from the limited information you provide.

Comment: I don't even know what goes on in the server room (I've never been there before) so all my internet traffic can be linked to the userID I used to log into the network right? That's a toast if yes.

Comment: @Prodigy If they have the motivation and the technical competence, then the answer is likely "Yes". It would be safe to assume you are being monitored, but not safe to rely on it.